# Combine periodically and zoneschedule in flutter local notification,

Tags: flutter, push-notification, scheduled-tasks, repeat, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to use a local notification flutter and try to combine periodicallyshow and zonescheduled,

Can anyone give a link or example reference?
Thank you

> PERIODICALLYSHOW CODE

```
 void scheduleNotification(String title, String body) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channelIs',
      'channelName',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
    );

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      0,
      title,
      body,
      RepeatInterval.daily,//NOTE - repeat daily datetime(now) when press
      notificationDetails,
    );
  }
```

> ZONESCHEDULLED

```
static Future scheduleNotification({
    int id = 0,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    String? payload,
    required DateTime scheduledDate,
  }) async =>
      _notification.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        _scheduleDaily(const Time(07, 30)),//NOTE - SCHEDULE SPECIFIC TIME
        await _notificationDetails(),
        payload: payload,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
      );
  static tz.TZDateTime _scheduleDaily(Time time) {
    final now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    final scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime(
      tz.local,
      now.year,
      now.month,
      now.day,
      time.hour,
      time.minute,
      time.second,
    );

    return scheduledDate.isBefore(now)
        ? scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1))
        : scheduledDate;
  }
```

**When I run the function, it will run the notification repeatedly at the specific at 10:00 that I have determined**